# CKEditor broken html code

Tags: php, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor but when I post the form it breaks it's html code.
when I dump the post variable I get something like this:

```
<p  center;">text here</p>
```

it should be

```
<p style="text-align: center">text here</p>
```

it does it with all formatting attributes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First, make sure that your backend code does not do this. I'm 99.9% sure that it's not a CKEditor. Unless you modified it somehow.

Comment: It might be helpful to see/study how you POST, persist and view the content.